# Codeigniter 3.1.9 : 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm Upgraded the Codeigniter version 2.2.0 into 3.1.9 and Faced the some issue in localhost and fixed it. Then I pushed the same code into server. It will shows the 404

> Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Did you follow every step in [the migration guide here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html) and [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is some case

1) Check htaccess if you are on new server sometime server not allow the .htaccess so try to load page with index.php

2)Make controller name Camel case in 3.0 its require

Hope its useful for you 
Thanks

Comment: No, It's not a new server. I tried camel case. but No Luck!

Comment: Anyother possibility to fix this issue

Comment: @RajaC, how about following all of the steps in [the migration guides](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) instead of us making a bunch of random suggestions where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: @sparky thank you for your suggestions. We already followed all migration steps. So only it's working fine in our local environment. But I faced issue when push into server.Now everything good.